# Rounding error with bigint ticks to datetime in SQL

Tags: .net, sql-server, datetime

At our .NET front-end we are using ticks to handle time localization and at the database we are storing all values in UTC. Today we came across an odd rounding error when storing records to the database, we are using the following formula to convert Ticks to a datetime.

```
CAST((@ticks - 599266080000000000) / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60 AS datetime)
```

It seemed to work fine for most time values we tried until we discovered the following rounding error:

```
DECLARE @ticks bigint = 635953248000000000; -- 2016-04-04​ 00:00:00.000
SELECT CAST((@Ticks - 599266080000000000) / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60 AS datetime)
-- Results in 2016-04-03 23:59:59.997
```

The question is: What is causing this rounding error and what would be the best practice to fix it?

Comment: Using ticks instead of actual dates and times sounds more like a way to *introduce* timezone problems, not solve them. SQL Server has the `datetimeoffset` type that allows specifying a timezone in the value itself, without requiring conversions to/from arbitrarily based ticks and assumed offsets

Comment: Why don't you use DateTimeOffset at the front-end and datetimeoffset in the database? That would remove the ambiguities that are *still* present when using ticks with an assumed UTC offset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture your calculation in a sql_variant you can determine what type it is. In your case the calculation uses a numeric type which is not an exact datatype and this is where the rounding is occurring:

```
DECLARE @myVar sql_variant = (@Ticks - 599266080000000000) / 10000000 / 24 / 60 / 60 

SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@myVar,'BaseType') BaseType,
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@myVar,'Precision') Precisions,
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@myVar,'Scale') Scale,
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@myVar,'TotalBytes') TotalBytes,
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@myVar,'Collation') Collation,
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@myVar,'MaxLength') MaxLengths
```

which produces the following output:

```
BaseType    Precisions  Scale   TotalBytes  Collation   MaxLengths
numeric     38          18      17          NULL        13
```

I have found this code which works from  [Extended.Net link](http://extendeddotnet.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/convert-net-datetimeticks-to-t-sql.html)

```
DECLARE @ticks bigint = 635953248000000000

-- First, we will convert the ticks into a datetime value with UTC time 
 DECLARE @BaseDate datetime; 
 SET @BaseDate = '01/01/1900'; 

 DECLARE @NetFxTicksFromBaseDate bigint; 
 SET @NetFxTicksFromBaseDate = @Ticks - 599266080000000000; 
-- The numeric constant is the number of .Net Ticks between the System.DateTime.MinValue (01/01/0001) and the SQL Server datetime base date (01/01/1900) 

 DECLARE @DaysFromBaseDate int; 
 SET @DaysFromBaseDate = @NetFxTicksFromBaseDate / 864000000000; 
-- The numeric constant is the number of .Net Ticks in a single day. 

 DECLARE @TimeOfDayInTicks bigint; 
 SET @TimeOfDayInTicks = @NetFxTicksFromBaseDate - @DaysFromBaseDate * 864000000000; 

 DECLARE @TimeOfDayInMilliseconds int; 
 SET @TimeOfDayInMilliseconds = @TimeOfDayInTicks / 10000; 
-- A Tick equals to 100 nanoseconds which is 0.0001 milliseconds 

 DECLARE @UtcDate datetime; 
 SET @UtcDate = DATEADD(ms, @TimeOfDayInMilliseconds, DATEADD(d, @DaysFromBaseDate, @BaseDate)); 
-- The @UtcDate is already useful. If you need the time in UTC, just return this value. 

 SELECT @UtcDate;
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the issue and also gives a good reason why it happened in the first place. I didn't knew about sql_variant, great function for these types of calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following works:

```
DECLARE @ticks bigint = 635953248000000000; -- 2016-04-04​ 00:00:00.000

SELECT  DATEADD(s,(@ticks %CONVERT(BIGINT,864000000000))/CONVERT(BIGINT,10000000),DATEADD(d,@ticks /CONVERT(BIGINT,864000000000)-CONVERT(BIGINT,639905),CONVERT(DATETIME,'1/1/1753')))
-- Results in 2016-04-04​ 00:00:00.000
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f119d62-68fd-443e-aa20-3414e42d5f78/converting-bigint-to-datetime2-where-the-value-begin-with-digits-apart-from-1?forum=transactsql)

I couldn't tell you where the rounding error originates though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes about because `datetime` does not have the precision to store values down to the millisecond:

> datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187819.aspx)

Your value comes out as `42462.000000000000000000` which if I convert to a DateTime in C# comes out as 2016-04-03 23:59:59.995 which will get rounded to .997 by SQL.

Comment: Using datetimeoffset in the database and DateTimeOffset in the application would solve the problem *and* get rid of ticks